# Has apache security updates been backported?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, apache2, backport

I have Apache 2.4.7 on my Ubuntu 14.04. I regularly upgrade packages by running `sudo apt-get upgrade`. I would have expected that to upgrade Apache as well, but I didn’t seem to have happened. I’ve been reading about this backporting which refers to applying security fixes to older versions of packages (?).

My question is, how can I check if my Apache has gotten its security updates through backporting?

Comment: Security fixes are always patched - usually by backporting the patches to the target affected OS.  You can see outstanding unpatched publicly disclosed security risks at https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/apache2.html for Apache.

Comment: Ok. Is there some page where I can get a verification for that? For example CVE-2014-3523 can't be found from the changelog url provided by @user535733 [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+changelog) and therefore I think that the vulnerability has not been patched on Apache 2.4.7.

Comment: I will add checking individual CVEs to my answer once I get to a computer.

Comment: @ThomasWard could you add checking individual CVEs to your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to check if your Apache is getting security updates:

**Look at [the changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+changelog).**

Here's an example of a changelog entry showing a security fix:

```
2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13
Published in trusty-updates on 2016-07-18
Published in trusty-security on 2016-07-18
apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13) trusty-security; urgency=medium

* SECURITY UPDATE: proxy request header vulnerability (httpoxy)
 - debian/patches/CVE-2016-5387.patch: don't pass through HTTP_PROXY in server/util_script.c.
 - CVE-2016-5387
* This update does _not_ contain the changes from (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.12) in trusty-proposed.
```

**Common Mistake: Security Updates are NOT Backports**

Let's say the Foo Project discovers a security vulnerability in Foo 1.1. They issue a patch. Since most users have no idea how to apply the patch, they also release a new upstream version Foo 1.2 and suggest everybody upgrade.

The Ubuntu Security Team does not package Foo 1.2. Instead, they patch Foo 1.1. They upload the patched version as `Foo 1.1ubuntu0`. When you check your Foo version, it confusingly still says '1.1', and your cheesy tech-news website says '1.1' is vulnerable. **Check the package version and the changelog to see which security patches have been applied.** Do NOT rely upon the software's --version feature. The Ubuntu Security Team won't change that string.

Foo 1.2 appears in the next release of Ubuntu. You can upgrade to the shiny new features then.

After Foo 1.2 is released in a later version of Ubuntu, some intrepid users will try the newer package on their older release of Ubuntu. *Backporting* in Ubuntu is this method of porting newer packages to older releases. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Backporting in Ubuntu has nothing to do with security updates.

Be aware that the 'trusty-security' repository is fully supported by Ubuntu. The 'trusty-backports' repository is not supported - user beware.